# FastCGI FCGX_Accept_r accept request fails when accessing OpenCL Platforms

Tags: c++, apache, opencl, fastcgi, mod-proxy

I want to use OpenCL within my FastCGI application written in C++. However, the FCGX_Accept_r method returns an error (-9) after I use the OpenCL framework. I do not get any exceptions or other errors, the first request is completely processed and returns a valid response, but then the accept loop breaks. I boiled it done to this minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fcgio.h"
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    // Backup the stdio streambufs
    streambuf * cin_streambuf  = cin.rdbuf();
    streambuf * cout_streambuf = cout.rdbuf();
    streambuf * cerr_streambuf = cerr.rdbuf();

    FCGX_Request request;

    FCGX_Init();
    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);

    while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0) {
        fcgi_streambuf cin_fcgi_streambuf(request.in);
        fcgi_streambuf cout_fcgi_streambuf(request.out);
        fcgi_streambuf cerr_fcgi_streambuf(request.err);

        cin.rdbuf(&cin_fcgi_streambuf);
        cout.rdbuf(&cout_fcgi_streambuf);
        cerr.rdbuf(&cerr_fcgi_streambuf);

        // Access OpenCL
        std::vector<cl::Platform> platformList;
        cl::Platform::get(&platformList);

        cout << "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
        for(size_t i = 0; i < platformList.size(); ++i) {
                std::string platformName;
                platformList[i].getInfo((cl_platform_info)CL_PLATFORM_NAME, &platformName);
                cout << platformName << "\n";
        }

        // Note: the fcgi_streambuf destructor will auto flush
    }

    // restore stdio streambufs
    cin.rdbuf(cin_streambuf);
    cout.rdbuf(cout_streambuf);
    cerr.rdbuf(cerr_streambuf);

    return 0;
}
```

It can be compiled using

```
g++ main.cpp -lfcgi++ -lfcgi -lOpenCL
```

And the fastcgi process spawned by

```
spawn-fcgi -p 1337 a.out
```

On the first request it returns "Intel(R) OpenCL", Afterwards the service is unavailable.

My setting: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Apache webserver with mod_proxy_fcgi, g++ v 5.4.0, fcgi libraries from the Ubuntu repository and the Intel OpenCL environment.

Do you have any idea why the event loop breaks or how i can debug this? Could it be a bug in the OpenCL implementation or libfcgi?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Update:** I found out using strace that OpenCL closes filedescriptor 0 (stdin). That's why FCGI stops working afterwards and it also explains why a simple program only outputting the platforms returns without errors. As a workaround I use the dup() function to save the stdin filedescriptor and dup2() to put it back after using OpenCL.